# include twitter bootstrap in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I want to include `twitter-bootstrap` in one of my rails app.

I added the gem `gem twitter-bootstrap-rails` in my `Gemfile`. And I did the bundle install.

But I didn't see the bootstrap's css and js files under the assets of my app.

Do I need to generate them?

Or should I simply download latest `bootstrap` zip file and add them to my app?

So, I want to know what's the best way to include bootstrap in a rails app.

Comment: Did you run generator "rails generate bootstrap:install static"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install bootstrap-sass gem and sass-rails gem. after that rename your application.css file to application.scss and add below code

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Please check bootstrap gem github page 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

look up the *bootstrap-sass* gem, its more efficient and practical. You d definitely want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

After running bundle install, run the bootstrap generator to add Bootstrap includes into your assets using the following command:

```
rails generate bootstrap:install less
```